# Get if a current script Powershell is executed as Administrator (Run as Administrator)

Tags: c#, powershell, access-denied

I have Windows Service C# with credentials for user UserInstallerMoss.

Windows Service execute an EXE Console Aplicaction C# with credentials UserInstallerMoss.

EXE Console Aplicaction executes powershell.exe with credentials UserInstallerMoss.

Server is Windows Server 2012 Enterprise. UAC is disabled.

UserinstallerMOss is local administrator

Powershell functions returns $true value:

```
$ok = IsCurrentUserAdmin
$ok = IsCurrentUserAdmin2
```

but the script fails about "access denied"

> nativehr: 0x80070005 OWSSVR.DLL - Access denied

How can I get if a current script Powershell is executed as Run as Administrator?

How can I get if a current user in script Powershell is Administrator?

My functions returns true, but maybe it was wrong?

Powershell functions:

```
Function IsCurrentUserAdmin
{
    $ident = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent() 

    foreach ( $groupIdent in $ident.Groups ) 
    { 
        if ( $groupIdent.IsValidTargetType([Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]) ) 
        { 
            $groupSid = $groupIdent.Translate([Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]) 
            if ( $groupSid.IsWellKnown("AccountAdministratorSid") -or $groupSid.IsWellKnown("BuiltinAdministratorsSid"))
            { 
                return $TRUE 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return $FALSE 
} 

Function IsCurrentUserAdmin2
{
    $user = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent();
    (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $user).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if script is running elevated:

```
function Test-RunningElevated{
    # returns True if running elevated, otherwise returns False
    $windowsIdentity=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
    $windowsPrincipal=new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($windowsIdentity)
    $adm=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator
    Write-Output ($windowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adm))
}
```

IF you want to test if user running script is member of local administrators group:

```
function Test-LocalAdministrator{
    $currentUser = $env:USERNAME
    $currentComputer = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    $adminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$currentComputer/Administrators"
    $adminGroup.Members() | ForEach-Object{
        $member = $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
        if($member -eq $currentUser){
            Write-Output $true
            break
        }
    }
    Write-Output $false
}
```

Use them like this:

```
if(Test-RunningElevated){
    # code to run goes here
}
else{
    Write-Warning 'This script needs to be run elevated!'
}
```

Note that the Test-LocalAdministrator only checks direct memberships.

Comment: That is the same that IsCurrentUserAdmin2 function

Comment: And it return false even though you run the script elevated?